# Why pillow cannot identify this PNG file?

Tags: png, python-3.6, python-imaging-library

I used the following code to open `1.png` and got some error:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("1.png")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2519, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file '1.png'
```

But I can open `1.png` successfully with macOS `Preview`.

I am using Pillow 4.2.1 in Python 3.6.2.

Here is the image file https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbi2io1mb6p9cfi/1.png

Comment: I see the same error as you see, but I also get an error if I just try to open the image in Preview. When I open the image in the browser, there is no problem. I think there is something fishy going on with the image file itself.

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded your link from `Save link as`, I downloaded a corrupt file. I couldn't open it from `PIL Image`, but also not with the `Preview` app.

When I first opened the file in Chrome, and then clicked `Download` from Dropbox, the file was not corrupted, and I could also open it successfully in `PIL Image`.